# Windows Batch Use of If and If not commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm working on a child batch file for a text-based game parent I'm tinkering with. I have to use an if not statement per my professor's instructions. I want to make it to where if the user chooses anything besides "Y" after choice, the program exits. I tried using 'if not exit' and 'if not y==y exit', but the program just loops back to the parent batch file no matter the input after choice.

How can I guarantee that my if not exit statement always closes the program? Note: Program is run from desktop

```
:: Child Batch File
@echo off
Title Halloween......
color 06  
echo set speech = wscript.Createobject("SAPI.spvoice") >> "temp.vbs"
set text=You cannot kill the boogie Man!
echo speech.speak "%text%" >> "temp.vbs"
start temp.vbs
pause
del temp.vbs
Echo Another Round??
Pause
cls
Choice
if y==y call scarymovie.bat
if not goto exit 
:exit
```

Parent Batch File:

```
@Echo Off
Title Slim Shady - Scary Movie
color 04
:start
set /a counter+=1
Echo You Have Run This Program %counter% times
Echo %counter% >> answers.txt
Echo Greetings Traveler, Scrawl Your Name Across The Screen
set /p name=
Echo %name% >> answers.Txt
Echo What's Your Favorite Scary Movie??
Pause
cls
Echo Press 1 for Halloween
Echo Press 2 for The Exorcist
Echo Press 3 for I Doesn't Afraid No Ghost
set /p movie=
Echo %movie% >> answers.txt
if %movie%==1 call Halloween.bat
if %movie%==2 call Exorcist.bat
if %movie%==3 Start www.SesameStreet.org
Pause
Cls
```

Comment: Y==Y is always going to evaluate to true. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_(command)#Syntax

Comment: why use set /p in the parent script an choice in the child script?

replace choice with a set /p again=, and then
IF NOT %again%==y exit /b

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with doing if & if not statements with a variable for choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if y==y call scarymovie.bat
if not goto exit
```

This is not how it works... the thing you mean with `if not` is `else`.
The common syntax is:

```
if %variable%==value (
echo true
) else (
echo false
)
```

`not` is only used to negate the condition like in "Is the variable anything but **not** this value":

```
if not %variable%==value (
echo not value
)
```

Further in your script there is unreachable code:

```
if y==y call scarymovie.bat
```

will always evaluate to true as @JeffBlock noted in the comments. The correct way for checking the result of the choice command is to check the value of the errorlevel:

```
choice
Goto label%errorlevel%
:label0
echo Y
Goto nextStep
:label1
echo N
Goto nextStep
```

Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear :)

Comment: Ahh I see, had no clue about errorlevels. I went with if and if not in the end , much simpler to wrap my head around for what I was trying to accomplish. Hopefully we cover choice in class today :) . Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome :) If my answer was helpful and solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the grey checkmark next to the answer. This will not only help to keep the site clean but also reward you :)